# algorithm from sorted array to sorted polynomial array

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, sorting, polynomial-math

Working on below problem, major idea is, (1) if `A` > 0, merge from two ends, and in this case, two ends comes with larger values comparing to middle of array, (2) if `A` < 0, merge from two ends as well, and in this case, two ends comes with smaller values comparing to middle of array.

Wondering if any smarter ideas for performance improvements (e.g. time complexity or other perspective), space complexity improvement or any bugs in my code?

**Problem**,

Given a sorted integer array X and 3 integers A, B and C. Return the corresponding sorted polynomial array.

In other words, apply A*x*x + B*x + C for each element x in the array and return the sorted array.

**Source code in Python 2.7**,

```
def f(v, a, b, c):
    return a*v*v + b*v + c

def sort_polynomial(numbers, a, b, c):
    result = []
    if a > 0:
        start = 0
        end = len(numbers) - 1
        while start <= end:
            if f(numbers[start], a, b, c) <= f(numbers[end], a, b, c):
                result.insert(0, (numbers[end], f(numbers[end], a, b, c)))
                end -= 1
            else:
                result.insert(0, (numbers[start], f(numbers[start], a, b, c)))
                start += 1
    elif a < 0:
        start = 0
        end = len(numbers) - 1
        while start <= end:
            if f(numbers[start], a, b, c) <= f(numbers[end], a, b, c):
                result.append((numbers[start], f(numbers[start], a, b, c)))
                start += 1
            else:
                result.append((numbers[end], f(numbers[end], a, b, c)))
                end -= 1
    else:
        raise Exception('invalid argument!')

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
    print sort_polynomial(numbers, 1, 2, 1)
    print sort_polynomial(numbers, -1, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Although this an interesting question and code, it does not fit here, but rather belongs to codereview - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have function

```
F(x) = A*x^2 + B * x + C
```

Find minimum or maximum (x value `-B/2A`). If extrema is inside your data range, get index with extremal value and fill output array from beginning (if minimum) or from end (if maximum) in merge manner - you have already implemented a sort of merging.

In this case (preliminary memory allocation, no inserting) complexity is linear O(N)

Comment: Love your answer, mark your reply as answer. Thnaks MBo.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the excellent answer from MBo, here is a possible implementation:

```
import bisect
import heapq

def f(a, b, c):
    return lambda x: a*x*x + b*x + c

def sort_polynomial(numbers, a, b, c):
    if a == 0:
        return map(f(a, b, c), numbers)              # No x^2 term? Just map!
    apex = -b / ( 2 * a )                            # Find min or max
    middle_index = bisect.bisect_left(numbers, apex) # Where to cut list in half
    numbers = map(f(a, b, c), numbers)               # Apply f
    l1 = numbers[0:middle_index]                     # Part before apex
    l2 = numbers[middle_index:]                      # Part after apex
    if a < 0:
        l2.reverse()                                 # Revert after apex
    else:
        l1.reverse()                                 # Revert before apex
    return list(heapq.merge(l1, l2))                 # Merge and return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
    print sort_polynomial(numbers, 0, 2, 1)
    print sort_polynomial(numbers, 1, 0, 0)
    print sort_polynomial(numbers, 1, 2, 1)
    print sort_polynomial(numbers, -1, 2, 1)
```